# How can I keep rownames when converting a matrix into a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, r-rownames

I want to convert a matrix to a data frame. When I use

```
df <- mat %>% data.frame()
```

, I lose the rownames. How do I keep them?

Comment: Try `mat %>% as.data.frame %>% cbind(rn = row.names(mat), .)`  BTW, `data.frame` keeps the row names as such.  If you use `data_frame`, it would strip off those.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: `mat <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2, dimnames = list(letters[1:2], letters[1:5])); data.frame(mat)` works fine for me

Comment: @akrun - won't the cbind convert it all back to a matrix again?  I think that all that is needed is `as.data.frame(mat)`

Comment: @dww  It wont' because the `cbind` is doing the cbind of data.frame with row names and here it disptaches `cbind.data.frame`  I suggested it in case the OP is performing such operations using tidyverse then the row names will get lost in the process

Comment: @akrun Thanks, as.data.frame() seems to work. What is the difference between using data.frame() and as.data.frame?

Comment: @user42485  You can check the difference here `as.data.frame(mat, ind = 5)` and `data.frame(mat, ind = 5)`  the former doesn't create a new column

Comment: @RussHyde, this might depend on R version

Comment: Then could OP post the R version they are using, please

Comment: works with R 3.5.2/`dplyr` v 0.8.0.1. Voting to close as unclear until version numbers get posted (possibly by someone else who can replicate the problem).

Comment: can't replicate the problem in base R.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I like to do it:

`myDF <- data.frame(columnNameILike = row.names(myMatrix), myMatrix)`

It just has the slight advantage that you can name the row.names what you like.

Example:

```
mat = matrix(c(1,2,3,2,3,4))
row.names(mat) = c("one","two","three","frour","frive","six")
df = data.frame(columnNameILike = row.names(mat), mat)
```

Comment: `data.frame(your_matrix)` already preserves the row names, but nice trick if you want to make a special column for the row names in the same line.