make df of just factors into wide format with percent of each factor (pivot_wider?)
So I have a raw dataframe which is a recording of occurrance of species A, B and C, from 5 quadrats, which looks like this:
df <- data.frame(quad_1=(c('A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C','B','B')),
             quad_2=(c('A','B','C','B','B','A','B','B','B','B')),
             quad_3=(c('A','B','A','A','A','A','B','C','A','B')),
             quad_4=(c('B','C','C','C','C','B','C','A','B','A')),
             quad_5=(c('C','B','B','A','A','B','B','C','A','A')))

And I would like pivot it, with 'quadrat' as one column and % cover of each of the species A, B and C as their own columns, like so:
df = data.frame(quadrat = (c('quad_1','quad_2','quad_3','quad_4','quad_5')),
            A = (c(40,30,20,50,60)),
            B = (c(10,10,30,40,10)),
            C = (c(50,60,50,10,30)))

I know the values aren't accurate in my sample data but hopefully you get what I'm aiming for - any help much appreciated!

Perhaps: sapply(df, table)

Follow up with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625594/how-can-i-keep-rownames-when-converting-a-matrix-into-a-data-frame

Base R:
as.data.frame.matrix(proportions(table(stack(df)[2:1]),1)*100)

        A  B  C
quad_1 20 40 40
quad_2 20 70 10
quad_3 60 30 10
quad_4 20 30 50
quad_5 40 40 20


library(tidyverse)
  
df |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "quadrat") |>
  count(quadrat, value) |>
  mutate(n = n / sum(n), .by = quadrat) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)

Result
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  quadrat     A     B     C
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 quad_1    0.2   0.4   0.4
2 quad_2    0.2   0.7   0.1
3 quad_3    0.6   0.3   0.1
4 quad_4    0.2   0.3   0.5
5 quad_5    0.4   0.4   0.2

